# iPad won't connect to Lumix camera

Tags: ipad, usb, camera

I have a new iPad Air (4th gen), and a Lumix GX9 digital camera. The first time I plugged the camera into the iPad using a USB C to USB Micro B cable, they immediately connected and I was able to transfer RAW photos to Lightroom. Ever since, every time I plug the camera into the iPad, it begins charging but nothing ever actually connects.

- If I connect the two while the iPad is locked, I get an "Unlock iPad to use accessories" message, but nothing happens when I unlock it.
- If I plug the camera into my Mac Pro, it connects immediately and is mounted as a regular volume.
- If I plug the iPad into the Mac Pro, nothing obvious happens, but I do see it detected and listed as a USB device in System Report.
- I have tried multiple USB C to Micro B cables, all with the same result. - I have reformatted the memory card in the camera and reset settings there.

Is there some other trick to getting iPadOS to connect to USB devices?

---

After more experimentation with a standard USB-C card reader, a second Lumix camera (DC-G9), and a variety of cards, I have some more data points:

- All cards (32 and 64gb, UHS-I and UHS-II) and formats (ExFAT and FAT32) work fine with a card reader connected to the iPad.
- All cards and formats work fine connected to a Mac running macOS 11 or a PC running Windows 10, either in a card reader or in the cameras.
- The iPad will only connect to the cameras with a 32gb card factory-formatted FAT32. The same card reformatted does not work in camera (but works via a card  reader or PC, as above).